# How do images impact the browser memory relative to JS?

Tags: javascript, image, google-chrome, browser, v8

I am curious about how media such as images relate to memory in the browser and the JavaScript heap. Explicitly, how many JS objects would be equivalent to a 2MB image?

Disclaimer － I acknowledge that question is too vague for a precise answer. I will provide some arbitrary constraints but ultimately I’m looking for a general way to look at this problem. Suppose I am building a chat app and considering keeping all the messages ever sent in memory, how might I calculate a tipping point for a reasonable number of messages to keep in memory? How do I factor in that some messages are images?

You may assume

- The browser is chrome.
- The image is in jpg format and loaded using `new Image()` in JS and then inserted into DOM.
- Each object has about three to five key-value pairs. Key-value pairs are strings or numbers ranging from small ints to strings of about 10 ascii chars.
- Suppose the 2MB image is visible on screen.

My intuition tells me that the memory cost of an image of 2MB is way less than the cost of  `JSObjects * (2MB / size_of_obj_in_bytes)`, because:

- The bytes of the image are not in JS land and therefore somehow compressed and optimised away.
- The objects will not exist in silo but references will be created throughout user code creating more memory when passed through functions.
- There will be lots of garbage collection overhead.

I don't know for certain that I'm right and I certainly don't know by how much or even how to begin measuring this. And since you can't optimize what you can't measure...

Disclaimer 2 - Premature optimization is the root of all evil etc etc. Just curious about digging deeper into the internals.

Comment: JavaScript Object are usually much smaller than images. The only problem is if the chat was so huge that the Browser can't hold all the images in the cache. That's not usually going to be a problem, unless you're keeping as many images, as say, on an messaging app on your phone, which holds every conversation since you started the first conversation.

Comment: Images may live in various places at the same time. For a 2MB image displayed in screen, you'll have one version in the HTTP cache, in the form of the raw binary file, you may have one version of the decoded image on the CPU RAM, and you will have version of the bitmap image in the GPU memory. Once decoded, an image is far bigger than the original file (usually compressed). For strings to take that amount of memory, you'd need a few big books... But browsers do manage their memory quite well, and modern devices have a lot of it. So unless you are already facing an issue, don't bother.

Comment: This question is indeed too vague for a precise answer, so the best answer I can give is: try it and measure. Be sure to use real(istic) data. For example, copy a year's worth of your own existing chat history from other apps into your self-written app.